# Найти сколько раз слово встречается в тексте c++

Tags: c++

Написал код на C++ для подсчета сколько раз слово встречается в тексте. Но программа считает все варианты, даже если это слово входит в состав другого слова. Пример: Текст: la lan hla la, jsla.
Программа выведет 5, хотя само слово встречается только 2 раза. Как доработать код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
string text;
string word;
int count = 0;

cout « "Введите текст: ";
getline(cin, text);

cout « "Введите слово для поиска: ";
cin » word;

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    text[i] = tolower(text[i]);

// проверка преобразования в нижний регистр cout « text « endl;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    if (text.substr(i, word.length()) == word){
        count++;
    }
}

cout « "Cлово " « word « " встречается в тексте " « count « " раз." « endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам надо проверять, что символы перед и после найденной подстроки являются разделителями (т.е. пробелом, табуляцией, запятой, скобкой и т.п.)

Comment: @avp можно ли в c++ создать массив из этих символов и проверить, входят ли символы перед и после туда?

Comment: Конечно можно. Собственно, литерал `#define SEPARATORS " \t.,() и т.д."` вполне годится. Проверять, например,  можно -- `if (i == 0 || strchr(SEPARATORS, text[i - 1]))` для начала слова. Только для поиска лучше использовать find, а не создавать substr-ом для каждого символа новую строку. И после найденного слова (даже если оно подстрока в др. слове) переходить к поиску  лучше не со следующей позиции, а с позиции после слова (прибавлять к i размер искомого слова)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую реализовать